# Use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with List

Tags: spring

I am using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to map String values from properties file and it works ok.

My question is if I can set something the this in my property file:
myList=A,B,C

And then map it to a list

```
@Value("${myList}")
private List<String> myList;
```

When I try that it puts all the values in one place of the list.
Is there any way to tell it to break this to a list by ","?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Spring Expression language:

```
 @Value("#{'${myList}'.split(',')}") 
 private List<String> myList;
```

If `myList=A,B,C` in property file this will result in `myList` (in the code) with the values `A`, `B` and `C`

Comment: Note that the original code would work without the .split(), if you're using spring 3 and you define a conversion service - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29970335/228369

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sections 6.5.3 (Inline Lists) and 6.5.4 (Array Construction) on [this link to Spring Expression Language Features](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html).

From the link:

> Lists can be expressed directly in an expression using {} notation.

```
// evaluates to a Java list containing the four numbers
List numbers = (List) parser.parseExpression("{1,2,3,4}").getValue(context); 

List listOfLists = (List) parser.parseExpression("{{'a','b'},{'x','y'}}").getValue(context);
```

> {} by itself means an empty list. For performance reasons, if the list
>   is itself entirely composed of fixed literals then a constant list is
>   created to represent the expression, rather than building a new list
>   on each evaluation.

I am not sure that this will work exactly like you would like it to with the `@Value` annotation in combination with the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, but it is worth a look.

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look but like you say may not work the @Value annotation

Comment: Just as I thought, doesn't work with @Value but thanks anyway

Comment: I was trying to use parser on the value held in the string annotated by value and got parsing exception.