# Reading a List from properties file and load with Spring annotation @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-properties

I want to have a list of values in a `.properties` file, i.e.:

```
my.list.of.strings=ABC,CDE,EFG
```

And to load it in my class directly, i.e.:

```
@Value("${my.list.of.strings}")
private List<String> myList;
```

As I understand, an alternative of doing this is to have it in the Spring *config file*, and load it as a *bean* reference (correct me if I'm wrong), i.e.

```
<bean name="list">
 <list>
  <value>ABC</value>
  <value>CDE</value>
  <value>EFG</value>
 </list>
</bean>
```

But is there any way of doing this using a `.properties` file?

#### P.S.

I would like to do this without any custom code if possible.

Comment: how to read List<int[]> range using @value

Answer (score 599, accepted):

Using Spring EL:

```
@Value("#{'${my.list.of.strings}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> myList;
```

Assuming your properties file is loaded correctly with the following:

```
my.list.of.strings=ABC,CDE,EFG
```

Comment: Gave me a "Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{'${my.list.of.strings}'.split(',')}"]
Did it work for you? Maybe I did something incorrectly.

Comment: Works perfectly when I try it. What Spring version are you using?

Comment: I checked it again using the same version you are using. Copied the Spring EL exactly as in the post and it works.
What is different though is if I make an error in my EL I get a `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException` exception and not `javax.el.ELException`.
Is your objected created by Spring?

Comment: Works perfectly with Spring 3.2.

Comment: How about empty property `my.list.of.strings=`? I would expect such functionality retruning empty list where here it will be one item (empty string), wouldn't it?

Comment: I created custom static method to do that. First checking whether the input String is null or empty, in that case return empty list. Otherwise do the split. You can call static methods in EL easily.

Comment: Also note that the suggested solution doesn't do trimming so values like `item1, item2,    item3` may give you result you don't really expect (hint: spaces).

Comment: If you need to trim empty spaces use regex for split argument.. something like `@Value("#{'${my.list.of.strings}'.split(',\\s*')}") `

Comment: Be careful not to put space before `#{` e.g. `@Value(" #{'${my.list.of.strings}'.split(',')}")` or it won't split property just provide list with one non splitted element.

Comment: Does it support in XML?

Comment: How can one read similar property and create a list of String in applicationContext.xml?

Comment: This does not work with `@CrossOrigin(origins = {"${allowed.cors.urls}"})` Anyone has solution for annotation level?

Comment: Can set be used here in place of list?

Comment: when I try to keep a default value for empty list by adding ': '. there's still one element in the list with value of null when i print the list. how to resolve this. @Value("#{'${list.whitelist: }'.split(',')}") List<UUID> WhiteList

Comment: my.list.of.strings={'ABC','CDE','EFG'}  If you use this syntax, then you don't need to use custom expression to split.

Comment: Outdated answer. Since spring boot 2 the string will automatically be split for you.

Answer (score 113):

Since Spring 3.0, you can add a line like

```
<bean id="conversionService" 
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

to your `applicationContext.xml` (or where you configure things).
As Dmitry Chornyi points out in a comment, Java based configuration looks like:

```
@Bean public ConversionService conversionService() {
    return new DefaultConversionService();
}
```

This activates the new configuration service which supports converting `String` to `Collection` types.
If you do not activate this configuration service, Spring falls back on its legacy property editors as configuration services, which do not support this kind of conversion.

Converting to collections of other types works, too:

```
@Value("${my.list.of.ints}")
private List<Integer> myList
```

will work with a line like

```
 my.list.of.ints= 1, 2, 3, 4
```

No problems with whitespace there, the `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` takes care of it.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert-Spring-config

> In a Spring application, you typically configure a ConversionService instance per Spring container (or ApplicationContext). That ConversionService will be picked up by Spring and then used whenever a type conversion needs to be performed by the framework.
>   [...]
>   If no ConversionService is registered with Spring, the original PropertyEditor-based system is used.

Comment: Java configuration:

 @Bean
 public ConversionService conversionService() {
  return new DefaultConversionService();
 }

Comment: Outside avoiding to repeat yourself with `split()` in every expression, it also properly handles an empty list instead of giving you `[null]`

Comment: It is not working if the property is overrided (Exists in multiple property sources.)

Answer (score 61):

If you are reading this and you are using **Spring Boot**, you have 1 more option for this feature

Usually comma separated list are very clumsy for real world use case 
(And sometime not even feasible, if you want to use commas in your config):

```
email.sendTo=somebody@example.com,somebody2@example.com,somebody3@example.com,.....
```

With **Spring Boot**, you can write it like these (Index start at 0):

```
email.sendTo[0]=somebody@example.com
email.sendTo[1]=somebody2@example.com
email.sendTo[2]=somebody3@example.com
```

And use it like these:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("email")
public class EmailProperties {

    private List<String> sendTo;

    public List<String> getSendTo() {
        return sendTo;
    }

    public void setSendTo(List<String> sendTo) {
        this.sendTo = sendTo;
    }

}


@Component
public class EmailModel {

  @Autowired
  private EmailProperties emailProperties;

  //Use the sendTo List by 
  //emailProperties.getSendTo()

}



@Configuration
public class YourConfiguration {
    @Bean
  public EmailProperties emailProperties(){
        return new EmailProperties();
  }

}


#Put this in src/main/resource/META-INF/spring.factories
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=example.compackage.YourConfiguration
```

Comment: I have a problem where the other solutions described here do not work due to escaped commas not beeing recognized. Is there a way to do this solution with Spring 4?

Answer (score 57):

If you are using Spring Boot 2, it works as is, without any additional configuration.

```
my.list.of.strings=ABC,CDE,EFG

@Value("${my.list.of.strings}")
private List<String> myList;
```

Comment: didn't work for me, I have to use the Spring EL as shown above.

Comment: or even `private List<String> myList;`

Comment: Yes it worked for me as well: I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6

Answer (score 49):

By specifying the the `my.list.of.strings=ABC,CDE,EFG` in .properties file and using

`@Value("${my.list.of.strings}")`
`private String[] myString;`

You can get the arrays of strings. And using `CollectionUtils.addAll(myList, myString)`, you can get the list of strings.

Comment: I get only the first String "ABC"

Answer (score 20):

Have you considered `@Autowired`ing the constructor or a setter and `String.split()`ing in the body?

```
class MyClass {
    private List<String> myList;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(@Value("${my.list.of.strings}") final String strs) {
        myList = Arrays.asList(strs.split(","));
    }

    //or

    @Autowired
    public void setMyList(@Value("${my.list.of.strings}") final String strs) {
        myList = Arrays.asList(strs.split(","));
    }
}
```

I tend to prefer doing my autowiring in one of these ways to enhance the testability of my code.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using latest Spring framework version(Spring 3.1+ I believe), you don't need to those string split stuff in SpringEL,

Simply add PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and DefaultConversionService in your Spring's Configuration class ( the one with annotated with Configuration ) e.g,

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean public ConversionService conversionService() {
        return new DefaultConversionService();
    }
}
```

and in your class

```
@Value("${list}")
private List<String> list;
```

and in the properties file

```
list=A,B,C,D,E
```

Without DefaultConversionService, you can only take comma separated String into String array when you inject the value into your field, but DefaultConversionService does a few convenient magic for you and will add those into Collection, Array, etc. ( check the implementation if you'd like to know more about it )

With these two, it even handles all the redundant whitespaces including newline, so you don't need to add additional logics to trim them.

Comment: The adding of this configuration is working but something strange happens:
I cannot use @Value for File type, I must change File with Resource.

Answer (score 12):

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6

My property file:

```
usa.big.banks= JP Morgan, Wells Fargo, Citigroup, Morgan Stanley, Goldman Sachs
```

My code:

```
@Value("${usa.big.banks}")
    private List<String> bigBanks;

@RequestMapping("/bigbanks")
    public String getBanks() {
        System.out.println("bigBanks = " + bigBanks);
        return bigBanks.toString();
    }
```

It works fine

Answer (score 10):

All the above answers are correct. But you can achieve this in just one line.
Please try following declaration and you will get all the comma separated values in a String list.

```
private @Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(projectProperties['my.list.of.strings'])}") List<String> myList;
```

And also you need to have the following line defined in your xml configuration.

```
<util:properties id="projectProperties" location="/project.properties"/>
```

just replace the path and file name of your properties file. And you are good to go. :)

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to phrase the annotation like this: `@Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('${my.list.of.strings}')}")`

Answer (score 6):

My preferred way (for strings, in particular), is the following one:

```
admin.user={'Doe, John','Headroom, Max','Mouse, Micky'}
```

and use

```
@Value("#{${admin.user}}")
private List<String> userList;
```

In this way, you can include also commas in your parameter. It works also for Sets.

Comment: What/where is the underlying code that does this conversion for Spring?

Comment: It's SpELl that reads property admin.user ( the '${admin.user}', see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) and then parses what is inside ( the '#{....}' syntax, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-value-annotations).

Answer (score 4):

you can do this with annotations like this

```
 @Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('${my.list.of.strings:a,b,c}')}") 
    private List<String> mylist;
```

here my.list.of.strings will be picked from the properties file, if its not there, then the defaults a,b,c will be used

and in your properties file, you can have something like this

my.list.of.strings=d,e,f

Answer (score 3):

*Beware of spaces in the values.* I could be wrong, but I think spaces in the comma-separated list are not truncated using @Value and Spel. The list

```
foobar=a, b, c
```

would be read in as a list of strings

```
"a", " b", " c"
```

In most cases you would probably not want the spaces!

The expression

```
@Value("#{'${foobar}'.trim().replaceAll(\"\\s*(?=,)|(?<=,)\\s*\", \"\").split(',')}")
private List<String> foobarList;
```

would give you a list of strings:

```
"a", "b", "c".
```

The regular expression removes all spaces just before and just after a comma. Spaces inside of the values are not removed. So

```
foobar = AA, B B, CCC
```

should result in values

```
"AA", "B B", "CCC".
```

Comment: The split() method uses internally regex as delimiter, so your example can be simplified:
<br/>
`@Value("#{'${foobar}'.trim().split( *, *)}")`

Answer (score 3):

In my case of a list of integers works this:

```
@Value("#{${my.list.of.integers}}")
private List<Integer> listOfIntegers;
```

Property file:

```
my.list.of.integers={100,200,300,400,999}
```

Comment: or @Value("#{${my.set.of.integers}}") private Set<Integer> setOfIntegers;

Answer (score 2):

I think this is simpler for grabbing the array and stripping spaces:

```
@Value("#{'${my.array}'.replace(' ', '').split(',')}")
private List<String> array;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Commons Configuration. It have built in feature to break an entry in properties file to array/list. Combing with SpEL and @Value should give what you want

---

As requested, here is what you need (Haven't really tried the code, may got some typoes, please bear with me):

In Apache Commons Configuration, there is PropertiesConfiguration.  It supports the feature of converting delimited string to array/list.

For example, if you have a properties file

```
#Foo.properties
foo=bar1, bar2, bar3
```

With the below code:

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("Foo.properties");
String[] values = config.getStringArray("foo");
```

will give you a string array of `["bar1", "bar2", "bar3"]`

To use with Spring, have this in your app context xml:

```
<bean id="fooConfig" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="classpath:/Foo.properties"/>
</bean>
```

and have this in your spring bean:

```
public class SomeBean {

    @Value("fooConfig.getStringArray('foo')")
    private String[] fooArray;
}
```

I believe this should work  :P

Comment: could you be more specific about the method and class to use, and actual sample code sniplet would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer

```
@Value("#{'${my.list.of.strings}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> myList;
```

works as expected for the comma separated values.
To handle null (when property not specified) added the default value(`': '`after the property name) as empty string as below:

```
@Value("#{'${my.list.of.strings: }'.split(',')}")
```

Answer (score 0):

if using property placeholders then ser1702544 example would become

```
@Value("#{myConfigProperties['myproperty'].trim().replaceAll(\"\\s*(?=,)|(?<=,)\\s*\", \"\").split(',')}")
```

With placeholder xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">   
    <property name="properties" ref="myConfigProperties" />
    <property name="placeholderPrefix"><value>$myConfigProperties{</value></property>
</bean>    

<bean id="myConfigProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
     <property name="locations">
         <list>
                <value>classpath:myprops.properties</value>
         </list>
     </property>
</bean>
```