# Escaping a | (pipe) in SpEL

Tags: spring, escaping, spring-annotations, spring-el

I'm hoping there is a very quick simple answer to this, I've read a few other questions on here that reference SpEL and escape sequences, but still haven't succeeded.

I would like to split a property into a list of String using `@Value` and SpEL. The property will be:

```
12345|12345|12345
```

So I need to split on pipe characters, I can do this in Java by using `.split(\\|)` to successfully escape the pipe character. I have tried with no slashes, 2 slashes and 4 slashes and all are unsuccessful. Is it possible to split on pipes using the following code? My client wants to keep using pipes for whatever reason...

```
@Value("#{'${list.of.blocked.people}'.split('\\|')}")
private List<String> myBlockedPeopleList;
```

Thanks.

Here is a link to the question that got me this far, for reference.

[Reading a list from properties file and load with Spring annotation value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value)

I also tried looking at the Spring Docs, but I couldn't find any reference to escape pipes  in their documentatin.

[Spring Documentation on SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-literal)

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer on a web development forum [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?134508-Regular-Expression-%28RegExp%29-Pipe-Match-Problem).

My solution was to basically give up on trying to escape the pipe character with back-slashes and use the unicode character escaped sequence. If anyone else is trying to pull in a pipe-separated String using @Value, the following code is tested and works with Java 6, Tomcat 6 and Spring 3.

```
// Reads blockPeopleString delimited with | and splits into List of Strings
@Value("#{'${blockPeopleString}'.split('\\u007c')}")
private List<String> blockPeopleList;
```

Comment: Was beating my head until I finally realized SpEL was treating it as an or. Thanks a ton. Also noticed simply '\\|' works.