# How to implement value annotation in a spring-batch

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

How do I implement @Value in a spring batch program.. any suggestions.. I wanted to get values from a property file, values like web-services end point, target then db details..

Comment: I have not implemented anything yet just wanted some info before I start..

Comment: Nothing to do with spring-batch, just spring-core. Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value?rq=1

Comment: I tried all that but am not getting the values from the property file to my tasklet in spring batch.. I just tried the example in mkyong site. Tried adding the properties file there but it didnt work. Can anyone please help..

Comment: you need to post your relevant configuration to let us help you