# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and keys with multiple values

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I've a properties file like this :

```
firstproperty=1,2,3,4
secondproperty=47,998,120
thirdproperty=54
```

My properties file is well defined in my Spring configuration as property for my PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer bean.

I want to load values in a

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

like this :

```
<util:map id="properties" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="first" value="${firstproperty}" />
    <entry key="second" value="${secondproperty}" />
    <entry key="three" value="${thirdproperty}" />
</util:map>
```

The problem is that for each entry, multiple values separated by commas count as one value. I tried to configure value-type of my util-map to an ArrayList but it was unsuccessful. Any idea ?

P.S : I use Spring 3.2.

Comment: You can visit this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: @Freeman thank you, actually I had read it and I was not totally satisfied, cause I need to manage my beans injections into Spring configuration file and not in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I searched Spring EL in config file, maybe this is what you want:

```
<bean id="taxCalculator" class="org.spring.samples.TaxCalculator">
<property name="defaultLocale" value="#{ systemProperties['user.region'] }.split(',')"/>

<!-- other properties -->
```

I am not sure about the location of split method, you can try yourself to find the correct way. For more details, please refer:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html