# Spring @Value To Data Structure

Tags: java, spring

my Properties file is like this

```
customer1.username = "";
customer1.passwword ="";
customer1.integratorkey=""

customer2.username = "";
customer2.passwword ="";
customer2.integratorkey=""
```

Is there a way I can use @Value annotation and load the value in a data structure with all the six values in it

Answer (score 1):

Java code with @Value annotation:

```
 @Value("${customer1.username}")
 private String customer1Username;
```

Comment: This does not works for me I want all the six values in a map or similar datastructure . I did know the simple usage of @value annotation

Comment: I couldn't find usage of @Value to inject bean list from .properties file, generally it's using for simple types , example code is :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value
You can define your bean list in your .xml file then inject to your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Bean and set the attributes with the properties. Something like this:

```
<bean id="example1" class="ar.com.whetever.ExampleImpl">
        <property name="attribute1" value="${customer1.username}" />
        <property name="attribute2" value="${customer2.passwword}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I would like to do it in java programmatically and not deal with the XML files