# spring bean from list<String> in a properties file

Tags: java, spring, list, javabeans, properties-file

I have a `file.properties` like this:

```
parameterkey=one
parameterval=oneVal

parameterkey=two
parameterval=twoVal

parameterkey=three
parameterval=threeVal
```

How can I set the property bean to wire parameterkey string list and parameterval string list?

Now I have this, but it wires only the last parameter and value in the appropriate variable:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${env}.properties"/>
.....
<spring:bean id="myBean" class="mygroup.MyClass">
            <spring:property name="queryParamKey">
                <spring:list value-type="java.lang.String">
                    <spring:value>${parameterkey}</spring:value>
                </spring:list>
            </spring:property>  

            <spring:property name="queryParamVal">
                <spring:list value-type="java.lang.String">
                        <spring:value>${parameterval}</spring:value>
                </spring:list>
            </spring:property>
</spring:bean>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure this can help you (especially the second answer)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value

Comment: Just make it a comma separated list `parameterkey=one,two-three`... Spring will do the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this in the properties

```
app.myType[0].key=key1
app.myType[0].value=val1
app.myType[1].key=key2
app.myType[1].value=val2
```

you can have @ConfigurationProperties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app")
@Component
public class PropertiesConfiguration {
    private List<MyType> myType;

    public static class MyType {
        private String key;
        private String value;

        //getters setters
    }
    //getters setters
}
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml) for more details.

Comment: I create a PropertiesConfiguration  class, but @configurationproperties is unresolved. What may be wrong? Thanks

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` are a Spring Boot feature. I strongly suggest using Spring Boot instead of plain Spring configuration. You can scaffold a spring boot project from http://start.spring.io/ or from Spring Tool Suite.