# preprocess configuration values in Spring

Tags: spring

In a Spring bean, I need to process a configuration property before using is, e.g.:

```
@Component
class UsersController {

  @Value("${roles}")
  private String rolesAsString;

  private List<String> roles;

  @PostConstruct
  public void initRoles() { 
    // just an example, not necessarily string splitting
    roles = rolesAsString.split(",");
  }
```

This works, but I am left with an unneeded member variable 'rolesString'. What would be a clean concise way to only keep the processed value?

Comment: [check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580260/1599937)

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I should have been more specific that I mean any preprocessing, as mentioned in the title, and not just splitting a string, as in the example.  I will add a comment in the initRoles method to reflect that. The answer provided by Essex Boy is the answer from the link already provided by Aleksei.

Answer (score 1):

Properties is

```
roles=role1,role2,role3
```

Code is :

```
@Value("#{'${roles}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> roles;
```