# How to inject list by @Value?

Tags: java, spring

application.properties:

```
my.list=1,2,3,4
```

I want to inject this as a `List` into a `@Value` field:

```
@Value("${my.list}")
List<Integer> list;
```

On the net I found that the following bean has to be registered for this to work:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService() {
    return new DefaultConversionService();
}
```

Result:

```
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.List];
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,2,3,4"
```

Somehow `spring` is not trying to parse this as a list. Why?

I know it is possible using spEL with `@Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',')}")`, but I'm explicit looking in a solution without spel conversation.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: yes using `spring-boot` 1.3.5

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value

Comment: Yes using `Spring EL` works, but the docs state it should be possible using `DefaultConversionService` without spel. Btw: this question is thus NOT answered in the linked question.

Comment: boot has the conversion service registered by default and it works fine as `List<String>`. Maybe it's a bug/feature?

Comment: This works fine for me. Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score -1):

Spring is looking for a setter like setList(String), since there isn't, tries to convert the value. You can solve that by creating a setList(String[] arg) method witch parses each element of arg and then sets the list

```
setList(String[] arg){
    if (arg == null){
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(arg.length);
        for (String s : arg){
            this.list.add(Integer.parse(s));
        }
    }
}
```

I think Spring can access such setter even if it's private, but try with public first, and then reduce visibility if it works

Comment: Spring doesn't need a setter to inject a `@Value` annotated field.

Comment: It does if the value (String in the case of properties) can't be converted to the field's type (List<Integer>)