# Creating a spring bean for each property

Tags: spring

I'm trying to figure out a way for getting a property values list, for example

```
test.property = val1, val2, val3
```

and for each value added, create at runtime another bean of the same certain type, with the added value.

Basically, getting the properties is not the issue, but creating the beans by them.
If i'm trying to use BeanFactoryPostProcessor to create the new beans, the properties are null in the phase of postProcessBeanFactory...

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. If you want more detailed answer, you should better explain what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I think you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value

Comment: @SergeBallesta I want to get a list of strings, and for each string create a bean of class type Foo, and set it inside.
I've heared about BeanFactoryPostProcessor, but on 'postProcessBeanFactory' I dont get the properties yet (too early in the lifecycle)

Comment: @EssexBoy I know how to get the properties, just not how to create the bean from them. thanks

Comment: There are different ways, java config, xml config, pre 2.0 xml config... Show what you have tried in the question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm using java config

@Value("${test.property}")
private Collection<String> values;

Comment: Where is your *certain type*s and what are they. Should be detailed. Give some bean definitions you have