# Spring @Value empty list as default

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

Is there a way to set an empty list as default value for a property in Spring, something like:

```
@Value("${my.list.of.strings :" + new ArrayList<>() + "}")
private List<String> myList;
```

Obviously not new ArrayList, but I need an empty list there instead.

Comment: Is `private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>()` not enough?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After taking a look at SpEL specification and combined with @javaguy's answer I came up with this:

```
@Value("${my.list.of.strings:}#{T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()}")
private List<String> myList;
```

Comment: your answer is helpful but incomplete, since the value annotation points to a property in the first place (which should be initialized when not present - otherwise it leads to an IllegalArgumentException)

Comment: I have used that for zero sized `list` in my project and did not get any `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: don't know about your code but mine breaks if I specify a property where there's no default value and does not come up in any property file

Comment: Seems it works, but no idea why. I would expect that empty list directly after colon and not after closing parenthesis }.

Comment: Whit what logic this work? How $ and # in the same annotation can work like this? 

It seems to work , but why? could you please explain? @RobyRodriguez

Comment: It's really much simpler with @sf_ 's answer

Answer (score 25):

Actually, in the current Spring versions works just one symbol `:` with an `empty default`value.

The full example that I'm using:

```
@Value("${my.custom.prop.array:}")
private List<Integer> myList;
```

To be sure and safer I also adding init to the List variable:

```
@Value("${my.custom.prop.array:}")
private List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This solution requires `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` as reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29970335/685806

Answer (score 4):

```
@Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('${my.list.of.strings:}')}")
private List<String> myList;
```

works for me, using Spring 5.0.x (gives empty list, if your my.list.of.strings property is not configured in context)

afterwards you can easily do something like

```
CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(myList)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Collections.emptyList()` **to populate the empty list object with zero size** as shown below:

```
@Value("#{T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()}")
private List<String> myList;
```

This will give you a zero sized `myList`

Comment: what's the significance of 'T' here ?

Comment: @flash, it is allowing to reinterpret the parameter as a class object. Next the static method `.emptyList()` is called on `java.util.Collections.class` class

Comment: In Spring version 6.0, it's also possible to create an empty list with `{}`, so that works too `@Value("#{{}}")`. See [inline lists](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/inline-lists.html).