# Java SpringBoot - @Value for en empty list

Tags: java, spring-boot

Small question regarding how to configure an empty list with an @Value via application.properties file please.

I have the following:

```
  @Value("#{'${my.cool.list}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> myList;
```

If I configure the following in my application properties:

```
my.cool.list=
```

I was naively expecting to have an empty list.

**But instead, I have a list one one element and the one element is the empty string**

How do I declare an empty list via application properties please?

I do not want to use some default mechanism from @Value, or remove the property if possible.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920606/spring-value-empty-list-as-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace (or trim) the blank spaces first:

```
@Value("#{'${my.cool.list}'.replace(' ','').split(',')}")
private List<String> myList;
```

With newer versions, you could also use `:` as operator for empty Lists:

```
@Value("#{'${my.cool.list:}'")
private List<String> myList;
```