# How to pass task properties (application ) parameters to spring cloud data flow task?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a task where the task requires initial values like list of student ids,

I was looking at the Spring Cloud data Flow UI screen, it shows that before launching we can  pass a property key  and a value pair.

**So if I create a property key as app.studentjob.property And give a property value as 11, 12, 13**

How to access this in the actual task in application code ?

Also when we are launching task from rest api, how to pass properties in the url http://localhost:9393/tasks/executions?name=studentjob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing the value of property from application.properties you would use Spring @Value annotation, here's a relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value)