# build a java list from properties file

Tags: java, spring

I have an a list of stores(getStore(..))s, which is getting all the stores from DB

what I'm trying to do is to add additional stores from properties file.(trying to build the list)

here's how my properties file look like

```
yard=1085:BELF:BELGRADE FIXTURES
yard=3238:SKWS:SKOKIE WAREHOUSE
yard=3239:PLDC:PLANO DC
yard=3339:HCDC:HOLIDAY CITY DC
```

here's how I'm trying to get the list.

```
@Value("#{'${yard}'.split(',')}#{T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()}") 
private List<String> myList;
```

here how I'm trying to add the additional stores to the list

```
    public List<Store> additionalYardList() {
    List<Store> stores = storesApi.getStores();
    for (String yard : myList) {
        String[] yardArray = yard.split(":");
        Store store = new Store();
        store.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(yardArray[0]));
        store.setAbbr(yardArray[1]);
        store.setName(yardArray[2]);
        LOG.debug(store.getAbbr());
        stores.add(store);
    }
    return stores;
}
```

Then will do a Stream to merge

```
    public List<Store> getAllStores() {
    return Stream.of(additionalYardList(), storesApi.getStores()).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

My Store object fields are: (number- abbr - name )

Nothing is been added to that list, Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: You can't do it like this. Each line needs a unique key. A properties file is like a HashMap. I don't see why you're using one at all. Just a file withh. each line being a new item would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate yard keys, please correct properties file to have unique keys.

Change it from

```
yard=1085:BELF:BELGRADE FIXTURES
yard=3238:SKWS:SKOKIE WAREHOUSE
yard=3239:PLDC:PLANO DC
yard=3339:HCDC:HOLIDAY CITY DC
```

To

```
yard=1085:BELF:BELGRADE FIXTURES,3238:SKWS:SKOKIE WAREHOUSE,3239:PLDC:PLANO DC,3339:HCDC:HOLIDAY CITY DC
```

And then you could load them with below code.

```
@Value("#{'${yard}'.split(',')}") 
 private List<String> myList;
```

This has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value).