# Multiple values of a property in Spring bean

Tags: java, spring

I need to set two values in Spring bean property value having same name.

Currently I have

I am using this property name as this in Java class : **private String siteUid;**

My requirement is to add another property name with diffrent value

Please suggest, if I can write both property values, and how can I use the same in Java class

Comment: Well, a Spring bean property always refers to a field of the corresponding Java class and there can not be 2 fields with the same name in a class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a List from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@Value` annotation.

If you have a properties file that contains:

```
foo.bar.property1=hello
foo.bar.property2=world
```

You can use in your Java class:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Value("${foo.bar.property1}")
    private String variable1;  // will be set to "hello"

    @Value("${foo.bar.property2}")
    private String variable2;  // will be set to "world"
}
```

Note that the names of the actual variables (i.e. `variable1` and `variable2`) are irrelevant; they can be whatever you want. The important part is that the string contained in `@Value` matches the key in your properties file.

Comment: Yes, silly mistake by me. I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear what do you mean by adding. In general as long as you're supposed to use `@Value` annotation the most flexible approach by far, is using Values in autowired constructor:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
   private String myProperty;

   public MyComponent(@Value('${app.value1}') String value1, @Value('${app.value2}') String value2) {
      // here you can even concatenate the value (hence I've said that its not clear what is 'add' but in general you can manipulate however you want
     this.myProperty = value1 + value2; 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring Expression Language here to add/concat two property

`@Value("#{'${property1}'.concat('${property2}')}") String parameter`

Here `concat` is the `String` method. As the requirement is not very clear to me, so you could experiment with other string methods to achieve what you want.