# Avoid repetitive values for @Secured annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to secure my service methods using `@Secured` as below:

```
public interface IUserService {

@Secured({"ROLE_ROLE1", "ROLE_ROLE2"})
    ResponseEntity saveUser(CreateUserDtoRequest userDto);

}
```

I wanna know is there a way to define `{"ROLE_ROLE1", "ROLE_ROLE2"}` in a variable and read its `value` from a `properties` file?
That would be great if you can suggest me a trick, to:

1. remove repetition of `{"ROLE_ROLE1", "ROLE_ROLE2"}` in other methods
2. In case of change in required roles to access a method in future, there would be no need to change the code, recompile and deploy it again.

Comment: You can work with `@PreAuthorize` in your application, but you could define user permissions and add them to user as a role.

User1 -> role_adming -> [save_user,edit_user]. 
This would look like that in your method:

`@PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyAuthority(" +
         "T(ua.pmdev.auctionizer.rest.user.domain.UserPermission).ADMIN.name()," +
         "T(ua.pmdev.auctionizer.rest.user.domain.UserPermission).ALL.name())")`

Comment: I do not have a problem to solve the issue with `@PreAuthorize` as there are already some solutions online. Since `@Secured` annotation is more appropriate to use in my case (simplicity and higher  readability due to not having `hasRole` stuff in it in addition to not having to use `conditionalEL`), I wonder is it possible to check dynamically the `roles` in `@Secured`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you need:

---

### Develop your custom `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations`

In this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) you will see how to deal with a new custom security method (*section 5*) or override the current `hasAuthority` one (*section 6*)

---

### Develop your custom method to use in `SpEL`

Probably an esier option, the steps could be the following ones:

**1.** Include the allowed roles in your `application.yml` (or `properties`)

```
security:
  rolesAllowed: ADMIN,USER
```

**2.** Define the class to check those roles and authorized user ones. For example:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

@Component
public class FromPropertyRoleSecurityCheck {

  private final static String ROLE_SEPARATOR = ",";

  @Value("${security.rolesAllowed}")
  private String rawRolesAllowed;


  public boolean verifyRoles() {
    return getPrincipalAuthorities()
            .map(auth -> {
                Set<String> rolesAllowed = Stream.of(rawRolesAllowed.split(ROLE_SEPARATOR))
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .collect(toSet());
                return verifyAllowedRoles(rolesAllowed, auth);
            })
            .orElse(false);
  }


  private Optional<Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> getPrincipalAuthorities() {
    return ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .map(Authentication::getAuthorities);
  }


  private boolean verifyAllowedRoles(final Collection<String> rolesAllowed,
                                     final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> principalAuthorities) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(rolesAllowed)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(principalAuthorities)) {
        return false;
    }
    Set<String> rolesDiff = principalAuthorities.stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(toSet());
    rolesDiff.removeAll(rolesAllowed);
    return rolesDiff.size() != principalAuthorities.size();
  }

}
```

**3.** Add the security check:

```
@PreAuthorize("@fromPropertyRoleSecurityCheck.verifyRoles()")
public ResponseEntity<MyDto> findById(@PathVariable @Positive Integer id) {
  ...
}
```

---

**If you don't want to recompile/deploy the project every time those roles change**, you can save them in an external storage like database for example (shouldn't be a problem to update any of provided examples to deal with such situations). In the second one I used a property to keep it simple, but is quite easy to include a `Repository` in `FromPropertyRoleSecurityCheck` to get them from database.

PD. Examples of provided link and custom one were developed in **Controller** layer, but they should work in the **Service** one too.

Comment: Thanks for your response @doctore. your solution seems neat and nice and I am vote it up. Also, I will try the solution and let you know the result.

Comment: The solution worked. thanks. just one little thing: there is no need for `ROLE_SEPARATOR` since you can define `rawRolesAllowed` as `List<String>` instead of `String`

Comment: Glad to help. Regarding `List<String>`, yes, there is easier ways to work with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value