# Forbid other users to see not their data with Spring microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I am working with microservices with spring boot.
I added security to the router and it works fine.
But I have no idea how should I implement solution that will allow users to
manipulate only their own data.

For example I have Book microservice

```
@RestController("books")
public clas BookController{

  @PostMapping
  public Book saveBook(Book book){
    return bookService.save(book);
  }

  @GetMapping("users/{userId}")
  public List<Book> getBooks(@PathVariable Long userId){
    return bookService.getBooksByUser(userId);
  }
}
```

Let's say book entity contains field userId. I would like to forbid other users
to save book with not their own userId.

I tried to do something like this:

- I added to posts mappings method url "users/{userId}"
- When user use endpoint POST "book-service/books/users/{userId}", then I check in
  router if userId from path matches userId from token.
- In my BookController, in method saveBook I override userId in Book entity with
  userId from path.

For me this solution looks not too good.
Is there other option to secure it on router level, or should I allow this request
to go to the microservice and there add another security level?
Can someone tell me what is a good patern to resolve this issue, or maybe
you can recommend me some Book/article/tutorial?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the following link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133772/avoid-repetitive-values-for-secured-annotation On the other hand, you can use in your custom authentication functions the endpoints parameters too: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression (sections `4.3` and `5.4` mainly)