# Spring Annotations - Config with Array attributes

Tags: arrays, spring, properties, configuration

Currently have the following configuration and the application works as expected:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "https://localhost:5000","http://localhost:5000"})
```

would like to change to something that can be configured in a properties file for different environments.  I Can get to work with one Value but can't figure out a way for it to work with more than one.  When a properties file is application-dev.properites has:

```
cors.client.urls=http://localhost:5000,https://localhost:5000
```

The appropriates values are not loaded with the following declaration:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"${cors.client.urls}"})
```

When the properties file is just one value this declaration works as expected.

I know that I am missing something extremely basic.. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpringEL here as mentioned in [Reading a List from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value)

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {#{'${cors.client.urls}'.split(',')}})
```

Comment: @CrossOrgin is defined at the class level. Maybe I am using an older version or some other lib is wrong but this does not compile..

Comment: This does not work at least in Java 11, I have a similar problem and when I'm trying to use this as `@CrossOrigin(origins = {"#{'${cors.client.urls}'.split(',')}"})` throws an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The [property] must resolve to a String. Resolved to [class [Ljava.lang.String;] `