# Dynamic String creation from property value

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I have my application.properties:

```
test.md5.params=something1,something4
```

In my java class I am getting this particular value :
and need to create same strings as present in the property file, such as

```
 public String calculate(RequestClass request)
       {
       List<String> params= //I am getting the values from application.prop  
        **(above part id done)**
```

My Question is below  ::
now in my params list I have `[something1,something4]`
so I need to concatenate both the String values like below:

```
       String finalString=request.getSomething1()+request.getSomething4();
       return finalString;
       }
```

My Question is how to do this dynamically and in my properties file I might receive "n" of something values.
Note : I need to make the code such that my class remains constant, if in future I am adding 10 more values in properties files, my final string should be returning like

```
   String finalString=request.getSomething1()+request.getSomething4()+....all the values.;
```

Comment: using `@Value` annotation with SPEL https://stackoverflow.com/a/12580260/9050514

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a List from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value)

Comment: That is done @deadshot , please read my question again.

Comment: from params how are you getting `request.getSomethingN()`, I don't see any correlation between these two thing.

Comment: yes, like param is asset_id for ex, so I need to get the value from request : request.getAssetId();

Comment: @TechGeek you don't need list in that case `@Value("#{'${test.md5.params}'.replace(',', '')}")`

Comment: What is `RequestClass`? Can't you have a `getValue(String)` method in it? If you change the configuration in your properties, won't you also need to update that class? (side note: I think the Spring part is irrelevant here, you should remove it from the question as it is confusing people, as seen in the comments and the duplicate proposal)

Answer (score 0):

Through reflection this is possible, below is one implementation.

```
public String calculate(RequestClass request) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<String> params = Arrays.asList("something1", "something4");

    // Do your logic to get the method Names from params, below is an simple example - paramsUpdated
    List<String> paramsUpdated = Arrays.asList("getSomething1", "getSomething4");

    // Reflection to get the methods of request class
    Method[] methods = request.getClass().getMethods();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (String param : paramsUpdated) {
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (param.equals(method.getName())) { 
                sb.append(method.invoke(request));
            }
        }

    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```